# Bazel fails to build tensorboard

Tags: java, build, tensorboard, bazel

I have Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS x86_64 and I tried to build [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard-plugin-example) repository with Bazel `version 0.17.2`

```
Build target: bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Fri Sep 21 10:31:42 2018 (1537525902)
Build timestamp: 1537525902
Build timestamp as int: 1537525902
```

After I launched this two commands:

```
bazel run //greeter_plugin:greeter_demo
bazel run //greeter_tensorboard -- --logdir=/tmp/greeter_demo
```

Bazel gives me this error(s):

```
INFO: Analysed target //greeter_tensorboard:greeter_tensorboard (1 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /home/julien/.cache/bazel/_bazel_julien/692ae2e42540ef65745334870839ed08/external/io_bazel_rules_closure/java/io/bazel/rules/closure/http/BUILD:17:1: Building external/io_bazel_rules_closure/java/io/bazel/rules/closure/http/libhttp.jar (10 source files) and running annotation processors (ComponentProcessor) failed (Exit 1)
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/Generated
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:158)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:96)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:90)
    at com.google.devtools.build.buildjar.javac.BlazeJavacMain.compile(BlazeJavacMain.java:111)
    at com.google.devtools.build.buildjar.SimpleJavaLibraryBuilder$1.invokeJavac(SimpleJavaLibraryBuilder.java:106)
    at com.google.devtools.build.buildjar.ReducedClasspathJavaLibraryBuilder.compileSources(ReducedClasspathJavaLibraryBuilder.java:54)
    at com.google.devtools.build.buildjar.SimpleJavaLibraryBuilder.compileJavaLibrary(SimpleJavaLibraryBuilder.java:109)
    at com.google.devtools.build.buildjar.SimpleJavaLibraryBuilder.run(SimpleJavaLibraryBuilder.java:117)
    at com.google.devtools.build.buildjar.BazelJavaBuilder.processRequest(BazelJavaBuilder.java:105)
    at com.google.devtools.build.buildjar.BazelJavaBuilder.runPersistentWorker(BazelJavaBuilder.java:67)
    at com.google.devtools.build.buildjar.BazelJavaBuilder.main(BazelJavaBuilder.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/Generated
    at dagger.internal.codegen.SourceFileGenerator.<clinit>(SourceFileGenerator.java:43)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor.initSteps(ComponentProcessor.java:119)
    at dagger.shaded.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.init(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:119)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ProcessorState.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:675)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors$ProcessorStateIterator.next(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:774)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:869)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$2200(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:108)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1206)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1315)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1246)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:922)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:142)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.Generated
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 23 more
Target //greeter_tensorboard:greeter_tensorboard failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 177.290s, Critical Path: 35.06s
INFO: 117 processes: 117 linux-sandbox.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

My OpenJDK version is `"1.8.0_181"`

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-b13)    
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

Could someone please help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You JDK shouldn't matter: bazel embeds a third-party JDK (by Azul systems). You can verify this with `bazel info`.

Now, the problem indeed is that is `@io_bazel_rules_closure/java/io/bazel/rules/closure/http` uses a very old version of Dagger which doesn't know about "javax.annotation.".

This is tracked in [issue rules_closure/#275](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_closure/issues/275)